# I am trying to create a box plot matrix using R

Tags: r, graphics, boxplot

I am trying to create a boxplot matrix using R. I want to show 18 box plots representing the numeric variable of "volume" from my data setand segmenting the volume by sex (categorical variables with 3 values) AND class (categorical variable with 6 possible values). I know how to break the boxplots out by one discrete variable, but not 2.

Comment: Reproducable example?

Comment: `d$group <- paste(as.character(d$class),as.character(d$sex)) ; boxplot(d$volume ~ d$group)` or just `boxplot(d$volume ~ d$class + d$sex)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably reach for the `interaction` function, which creates a factor variable for all n-way interactions, 2-way in this case.:

```
 boxplot( value ~ interaction(sex, class), data=mydat)
```